# Define Arrays in BigQuery schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following schema:

```
union{null, array<string>} catalog;
union{null, array<string>} schemas;
union{null, array<string>} tables;
```

I want to create the table on big query with the above schema. How to define the above fields in big query ?
I have used this:

```
  {
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "tables",
    "mode": "repeated"
  }
```

But big query is ignoring the data. Is this a correct way ?

Comment: What is the language used for specifying schema (first code block) in your question? can you also share an example of the data you are trying to load? Maybe a command that you are using for loading data would be also useful for better understanding the question

Comment: I assume it's Python type definition. But I don't understand what's your current problem. BigQuery ignore what? What's the result? In addition, the 3 fields: catalog, schemas, tables, are sequentials? Repeated? Can you share an example of the expected result in BigQuery (or on JSON format, or whatever the format, just to be clear on the expectation)